# Как в объекте поменять ключи и значения местами?

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};
```

Требуется перебрать этот объект и создать новый, в котором ключи - это значения объекта `obj`, а значения - это ключи объекта `obj`.

Я сделал вот так, но это решение не рабочее (при этом, рабочих найти не удалось):

```js
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 };
let obj2 = {};

for (let i in obj) {
  obj2[i] = i;
  for (let j in obj2) {
    j = obj[i];
  }
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно 2 цикла. `for (let i in obj) {` перебирает по ключам obj значит новый ключ это элемент `obj[i]` а новый элемент это `i`:

```js
let obj2 = {};
for (let i in obj) {
  obj2[obj[i]] = i;
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!